# App restarts after selecting an image from gallery in react native android

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I'm using react-native-image-picker module.
picking photos from gallery.Then restarts(sometimes) the app without showing any error, taking a photo from camera works fine.
I tried to upload image in firebase database.

Comment: okay how should anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Find an image that worked. Does it restart if you pick the same image many times? Perhaps one image works always, while another one crashes the system.

Comment: if user pick an image from gallery it's not working. take photo from camera working  fine i'm using react-native-image picker module

Comment: First screen 
Going to the camera or file selector no problem.

Escaping out of the camera or file selector view will crash the app.
Taking a picture and click ok button, or selecting a picture from the file selector will crash the app.

React Native version: 0.46.4
Platform: both
Development Operating System: MacOS,

Dev tools:Android Studio navigation crash for Android

This happens both on  physical device(tab)

Comment: how did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue?